# Navigation through internal links

Tags: html

For role 1 I have 3 tabs which are index.html,mng.html ,risk.html.Similarly for role 2 I have 4 tabs and for role 3 3 tabs.How should I write the code  in one file which will navigate according to the role.I have written it for role 1 as follows

```
<div class="tslcNav" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="mng.html">Manage</a></li>
            <li><a href="risk.html">Risk</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

According to me I need to write all the href links in one file and logic in another file. But how should I write the logic for roles so that file will display corresponding tabs only.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: How will you identify the role programatically? can you explain?

Comment: Suppose I have manager and employee role so for that I need to check which is the current role and according to that internal tabs should be displayed.Like if it is manager role then above 3 tabs should be displayed and other tabs should hide.

Comment: <% String link= request.getRequestURI(); %>  from this I can check the links But I am confused how to write the code for comparison like if link contain manager then hide other links